# Вывести количество определенных элементов массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
    <?php echo $order['order_type']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Выводит: 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2

подскажите как вывести и подсчитать кол-во определенных элементов в массиве

Нужно отобразить так:

Элементы с номером 2: 7

Элементы с номером 3: 3

Comment: `array_count_values` в помощь. и не надо менять вопрос так что целиком суть меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$counts = array();

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (!isset($counts[$order['order_type']])) {
        $counts[$order['order_type']] = 0;
    }
    $counts[$order['order_type']]++;
}

echo $counts[2]; // output 7
echo $counts[3]; // output 3
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно таким способом ([array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) + [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php)):

```
foreach(array_count_values(array_column($orders, 'order_type')) as $k => $v) {
    echo 'Элементы с номером ', $k, ': ', $v, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы проверкой сделал. иф !=3 не выводим.

```
if ($order['order_type'] != 3)
{
не выводим
}
echo выводим
```

Comment: в таком случае уж лучше сделать `continue`

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).